# jCarousel Lite Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jCarouselLite'

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I've followed this http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#install
through every step of the way, and can't seem to get any joy.

I've checked that the scripts are links and responding they all seem to be view-able in the debugger so I assume its nothing to do with that.

Any help to get this up and running would be great, Here is the website I'm trying to get it to work on and keep getting this error in the console:

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jCarouselLite'

http://goo.gl/58Ds2

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include the jQuery library which, I've checked, is not in the correct spot on that page.  You must include the JQ library before any script that uses it.  Either:

Pop this at the top of your page and delete line 21 (your current script)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

OR move

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/assets/js/jcarousellite.js"></script>
```

Below line 21 in your markup.

Your carousel script is dependent on the jquery library.  If jquery is not included BEFORE your script that uses it, you will get this error.  Make sure to place any jquery script declaration above any and all scripts that use/depend on it.

### Existing markup

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/assets/js/jcarousellite.js"></script>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Sportsrule, Sports event management and language services for sports teams, sports events and the sports industry</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/assets/style.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/assets/css/nivo-slider.css" media="all" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/style.css" media="all" />
 <!--   
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 -->


            <link rel="pingback" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/xmlrpc.php" />
            <link rel='stylesheet' id='NextGEN-css'  href='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/css/nggallery.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery.lightbox.min.css-css'  href='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/wp-jquery-lightbox/styles/lightbox.min.css?ver=1.3.4' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.9995'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.06'></script>
```

### Desired Markup

```
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Sportsrule, Sports event management and language services for sports teams, sports events and the sports industry</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/assets/style.css" media="all" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/assets/css/nivo-slider.css" media="all" />
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/style.css" media="all" />
 <!--   
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 -->


            <link rel="pingback" href="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/xmlrpc.php" />
            <link rel='stylesheet' id='NextGEN-css'  href='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/css/nggallery.css?ver=1.0.0' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.2.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery.lightbox.min.css-css'  href='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/wp-jquery-lightbox/styles/lightbox.min.css?ver=1.3.4' type='text/css' media='all' />

<!-- MOVED TOP SCRIPT INCLUSION LINE BELOW JQUERY INCLUSION RIGHT HERE -->

<script type='text/javascript' src='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.2'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/themes/Sportsrule/assets/js/jcarousellite.js"></script>


<script type='text/javascript' src='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.9995'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://176.32.230.13/test-getextra.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/nextgen-gallery/js/ngg.slideshow.min.js?ver=1.06'></script>
```

Comment: Now I'm getting the error twice, because I'm calling the same library once in the footer and in the header.Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jCarouselLite' 176.32.230.13:174
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'jCarouselLite' 176.32.230.13:571

Comment: yea sorry for not clarifying...you can only use one...so use the new one or keep the old...just make sure its above the script that depends on it

Comment: Sorry I'll slightly confused Mike, I've got both the file's you just linked in the header?

Comment: Well the second one I posted I copied from your page.  That one should not be included.  The problem is you are including the carousel script at the top of the page, before you include the jq library.  I'll show you what I mean in a sec

Comment: Ohh I think I understand what you mean, but I have the script running call back running in index.php and the script is under the src for the jquery library.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Thanks mike, I was running wp_enqueue_script('comment-reply'); which was calling some jquery before the script.

Comment: ahh...glad to be of help :)

Comment: do you know how i could possible add more visable pictures to?

Comment: thats another question my friend...give the library a whirl and see what you come up with, then hop back here to StackOverflow and ask away to your hearts content :)

Comment: I've just asked another question :)